# input text in div contentEditable, the cursor automatically jumps to the beginning

Tags: html, vue.js, contenteditable

Requirement: #Topic Functionality

Expectation:

1. When I type # followed by text, it should be highlighted.
2. Copying and pasting text should maintain the previous state. For example, if I copy `#Text#Text1`, after pasting, it should be `#Text#Text1`.

Current Issues:
When I input text, the cursor automatically jumps to the `beginning`. This is likely due to the use of `innerHTML`, causing the cursor to move to the front by default.
What I want is for the cursor to follow the text, similar to a textarea.

Here is sandbox link [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/serene-pine-djtzc7?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0007356o0mdvxoci%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0002356o41jfdhr4%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0004356ohm1xmhzk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0006356okm7u1so8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpp6ag2p0002356o41jfdhr4%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0002356o41jfdhr4%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clpp6ag2p0006356okm7u1so8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0005356o9o4p77jc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520run%2520dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0006356okm7u1so8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0005356o9o4p77jc%2522%257D%252C%2522clpp6ag2p0004356ohm1xmhzk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0003356otstlvlw2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520run%2520dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0004356ohm1xmhzk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpp6ag2p0003356otstlvlw2%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: You have to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretPositionFromPoint